# Syndicate all posts and photos made to Facebook

Tags: facebook, blog, synchronization

My family has a website that helps to keep us all in constant contact with each other.  Recently a good number of the younger family members have started to use Facebook.  Our little family website, still visited by a few older family members, is somewhat idle as a result.

Is it possible to automatically cross post all status updates and images from Facebook over to our family blog so that these little historical tidbits of information aren't locked away in the great Facebook network and the older family members who don't quite get Facebook can benefit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an easy solution, but Yahoo! Pipes lets you merge together multiple feeds and generate one feed that you can then embed on your site with a Pipe badge.  I use Yahoo! Pipes to merge together feeds from related sites so I have them all in one feed.  You'd have to grab the feed from each family member in order to do that.  More of subscriptions and feeds in Facebook can be found here: http://www.facebook.com/help/?topic=subscriptions

Comment: Yahoo Pipes was retired some time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Due to Facebook's privacy settings, there is no way for a user who isn't logged in to view most data from a user's Facebook profile, particularly images and status updates. The only way for you to achieve what you are trying to do would be to create a Facebook Application which each of your family members would have to add to their profile. That application could then export the data from their account and post it to the website. Start by checking out the [Facebook Developers site](http://developers.facebook.com/). This will require some programming, so this question may be more appropriate for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).